# Error missing values using .replace(regex)

Tags: python-3.x, regex, str-replace

I'm trying to replace some messy data with regex in a data frame, the column has qualification values, but they are messy. For example, I have 'plastic','plastique','Plasticpackage',or 'Karton','carton','Carton'... in the column 'packaging', but they all mean the same thing, that is 'plastic' or 'Carton', things like that. Therefore Im trying to replace all these values with .replace and Regex. My code looks like this:

```
dict1={r'[cK]arton':'Carton',r'\W*((?i)plasti(?-i))\W*':'Plastique',r'[cC]onserve':'Conserve'}

df['packaging'].replace(dict1,inplace=True,regex=True)
```

However, when i execute it gives me the error:missing : at position 18

I have checked, line 1 to line 18 have 17 missing values not only at line 18, so why i have this error? Should I tell python to ignore na values? But the replace() function does not seem to have the ignore na option.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: The error isn't due to `nan` values in the dataframe.  It's something odd with your second regex pattern.  `?` following a `(` as in `(?....)` takes on a different meaning than you might expect and only allows certain characters immediately following `?`.  I would suggest revisiting what you want to achieve with the `plasti`-containing pattern.

Comment: Do you have control over how the data is inserted? Maybe you can prevent inserting different values in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use inline modifiers in Python `re` at a non-initial position in a regex. Besides, it does not support `(?-i)` notation (to disable the effect of the preceding `(?i)`).

Instead, you can use an inline modifier group, `(?i:...)`.

So, you need to fix the regex definitions likes this:

```py
dict1={
    r'[cK]arton':'Carton',
    r'\W*(?i:plasti)\W*':'Plastique',
    r'[cC]onserve':'Conserve'
}
```

Or, `r'\W*(?i:plasti)\W*'` can also be written as `r'(?i)\W*plasti\W*'`.

Comment: Thank you. I used this regex r'\W*(?i:plasti)\W*' but it didn't match 'Glass,plastique' or 'Film en plastique' within python, however the regex tester said it matched (https://regex101.com/), logically it should match in Python, do you know why, please?

Comment: @Shyan What do you expect? Match words containing `plasti`? Then you need `\w`, not `\W`, e.g. `r'\w*(?i:plasti)\w*'`, see [this demo](https://ideone.com/beqG8t).

Comment: Thanks! I want to replace all values like 'plastic','plastique','Plasticpackage','Film en plastique','Glass,plastique' to 'Plastique', should the regex '\w*\W*\w*\W*(?i:plasti)\w*' be enough to do so?

Comment: @Shyan This is not in scope of this question, but I suspect all you need is `r'(?i).*plasti.*'`